# Replace incandescent lamps with LEDs in vintage christmas lights

Tags: led, incandescent

I have vintage Christmas lights with 20 incandescent lamp connected in series. They are connected directly to AC plug (220V here).

**UPD**: Original bulbs are 13.5V 160 mA (similar to https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32891974338.html)

I've ordered 12v LEDs with same socket from aliexpress (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002091249430.html). If I replace the old incandescent lamps with new LEDs, will it work? Or what is the simplest way to make it work with LED lamps?

Comment: Complicated but possible. So modification should be done. Make sure all bulb connected in series, plus to minus.

Comment: If the lamps survive having 220V AC across them (they are meant for DC), then they will flicker horribly.

Answer (score 2):

Under no circumstances can the details contained on the peebay page justify their selection when wanting to use 20 of them in series on a supply that is 220 volts AC. In fact the peebay page tells you that the LEDs are DC rated so this rules them out straight away.

If the peebay page said they were AC compatible then there's still no guarantee that one device wouldn't have its maximum AC voltage rating exceeded due to others in series wanting to take slightly more current.

Given that we know nothing about the original lamps in the vintage part, there's nothing that informs me (an engineer) that they might be at all compatible.

Comment: Thanks. Updated question with info on original bulbs.

Comment: @DenysPotapov I'm sorry but anything bought from peebay just doesn't cut the mustard in terms of a reliable specification or is from a reliable supplier with a known and recognized quality system. EE design requires both these things unless you want people to guess and, unfortunately, guessing and opinions are a reason to close some questions down.